# Why does document.getElementById('availability_view').scrollBy(300,0) not work?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.hash='today'; window.scrollTo(0,0);window.location.hash=''; document.getElementById('availability_view').scrollBy(300,0);">
```

Where availability_view is a HTMLDIVElement.

Console returns:

```
TypeError: '130' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementById('availability_view').scrollBy(300,0)')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, scrollBy() is a function of window.

If you are trying to scroll a div, use scrollTo.